# 20 devices connect to AP but one, but that one connects to all other wifi networks but my own?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wireless-access-point

Need help with something that actually doesn't make any sense.

TP-Link TL-WR743ND access point runs my home wireless network. It works great but... one device can't connect to AP. Something really weird happens and I can't find a problem on my own. I'm really not an expert but this is first time I'm facing something like this.

As I said, wireless network works fine for all devices in my home but one. That includes 3 tablets (Tesla L7 and 2 Galaxy Tabs), 12 smartphones, TV, XBox & 2 PCs (with USB TP-Link wireless sticks). I have problem with GoClever tablet.

Well, blind guess and bit of logic says that there's something wrong with that tablet but today I have tested that tablet with dozens of different wireless routers, ADSL modems and AP-s (even using hotspot on my phone). So, it was tested with almost 15 different devices because I was trying to find another device that my tablet **can't connect to** - with no success. Also tried factory reset on my tablet (Android 4.4.2). Everything worked well. Some of those devices have open connection, some were encrypted but all of them gave me an access.

**My question is, what the hell makes this problem?**

What have I tried so far. Tried to restart both - tablet and my AP (several times, using reset button and disconnecting it from power source for 10-15 minutes), tried to reconfigure AP, tried to OPEN password protected network, tried to use WPS, tried a bunch of things I could think about, but nothing helped. My tablet sees my SSID but after trying to connect always fails with 
"authentication problem". I have tried using filters (its MAC isn't blocked), tried to reserve static IP (AP uses DHCP to assign address in range x.x.x.100 - x.x.x.199 which is more than enough to handle all devices), tried to disconnect all other devices. That tablet isn't important at all, I rarely use it. I can always buy new AP and new tablet but that's not a point. It just drives me crazy because I have no idea what's the problem and that makes no sense to me. That tablet could connect to this network 20 days ago and since than I haven't changed anything (in tablet or AP) but last 15 days I was wasting hours and hours of time each day with zero success. My friend have same model of AP and I used his config file to try to restore on my AP (after some changes about input internet network) but again, all devices in my house works but mentioned one.

I'm confused. Obviously my AP works OK because almost 20 devices connects to it perfectly. It's also obvious that WiFi on my tablet also works fine because it connects to other spots.